# JTable - render a new status change

Tags: java, jtable, rendering

I am trying to change the color in a JTable following a notification from a listener but I have been unsuccessful.

Can someone please put me back on the good track?

```
class TableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer implements SensorListener {

public static final DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
private boolean status;

public TableRenderer() {
    status = false;
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Component renderer = DEFAULT_RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    Color foreground, background;
    foreground = Color.BLACK;
    background = Color.WHITE;

    if (status == true) {
        System.out.println(status);
        foreground = Color.WHITE;
        background = Color.RED;
        status = false;
    }

    renderer.setForeground(foreground);
    renderer.setBackground(background);
    return renderer;
}

@Override
public void updateOnSensor(int freq, String extremumType, double price, double support, double resistance, double lowestMin, double highestMax, double minimumTrailing, double maximumTrailing) {
    this.status = true;
    System.out.println("coucou");
    this.repaint();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems there.
First, you should call jtable.repaint() instead of this.repaint() in method updateOnSensor as it's the jtable should be re-renderred.

second, getTableCellRendererComponent will be called for every cell, if you set status back to false then only one cell will be re-renderred with new colors.

Comment: You should't have to call `repaint()`; updating the model should cause the view to update itself.